# Getting errors when evaluating a Manipulate expression

Tags: plotting, manipulate, warning-messages

My code

```
Manipulate[
  Panel[Plot3D[
    Re[H + Amp*Exp[-y*Abs[f]/Sqrt[9.81*H]]*
      Exp[I*(k*x - (Sqrt[9.81*H])*t)]], 
    {x, -80000, 80000}, {y, 0, 100000}, 
    PlotPoints -> 30, MeshStyle -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> 
      Directive[Opacity[0.65], Blue, Specularity[LightBlue, 10]]]], 
  Panel[Dynamic[
    StreamPlot[
      {Sqrt[9.81/H]*
        Re[Amp*Exp[-y*Abs[f]/Sqrt[9.81*H]]*Exp[I*(k*x - ω*t)]], 0}, 
      {x, -80000, 80000}, {y, 0, 100000}]]],
  {{t, 0, "Time {s}"}, 0, 1000},
  {{Amp, 20, "Wave Amplitude"}, 0, H}, 
  {{k, 0, "Waves per Metre (x-direction)"}, 0, 0.0005}, 
  {{H, 100, "Depth"}, 0, 500},
  {{f, 0, "Coriolis Coefficient"}, -0.01, 0.01}]
```

I keep getting the error:

> {2} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid
>   dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing

and

> Lists {System`ProtoPlotDump`vectordataextremes$1118273, System`
>   ProtoPlotDump`vectorcolorfunction\$1118273} and !({\"Range\", \
>   \"ColorFunction\"} /.  \"2\") are not the same shape.

I don't know what the problem is. I hope someone can help me identify the issue.

P.S. I am a relative beginner in Mathematica and am trying to plot a Kelvin Wave.

Comment: Your code seems okay here. Have you tried restarting the kernel?

Comment: No, I still get the same problem. Have you tried it in your own Mathematica? Does an error come up?

Comment: I tried it in Mathematica 11.1, it worked with no errors

Comment: And did you move the sliders, particulary that of the Coriolis Coefficient?

Comment: Yes, I moved all the sliders including the coriolis one. Can you identify a specific set of values for all sliders that induces the error?

Comment: Works fine here too. Try quitting Mathematica and trying again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not get the error messages you report in your question when I evaluated your code on my system (V11.1.1 running on OS X 10.10.2). I did encounter some other problems. The following minor rewrite seems to work well.

```
Manipulate[
  Column[{
    Panel[
      Plot3D[
        Re[H + Amp*Exp[-y*Abs[f]/Sqrt[9.81*H]]*Exp[I*(k*x - (Sqrt[9.81*H])*t)]], 
        {x, -80000, 80000}, {y, 0, 100000},
        PlotPoints -> 30, MeshStyle -> None, 
        PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.65], Blue, Specularity[LightBlue, 10]]]], 
    Panel[
      StreamPlot[
        {Sqrt[9.81/H]*Re[Amp*Exp[-y*Abs[f]/Sqrt[9.81*H]]*
           Exp[I*(k*x - Sqrt[9.81*H]*t)]], 0}, 
        {x, -80000, 80000}, {y, 0,100000}]]}], 
  {{t, 0, "Time {s}"}, 0, 1000},
  {{Amp, 20, "Wave Amplitude"}, 0, H}, 
  {{k, 0, "Waves per Metre (x-direction)"}, 0, 0.0005}, 
  {{H, 100, "Depth"}, 0, 500},
  {{f, 0, "Coriolis Coefficient"}, -0.01, 0.01}]
```

[image: demo]

Notes

1. I put the stream plot in the content pane with the 3D plot because I don't think you want to be treated as an annotation to the plot.
2. I give `ω` an arbitrary value because you didn't define it in your code.

#### Edit

I have updated the code to use the relation `ω = Sqrt[9.81*H]`

Comment: But the problem with this, is that $\omega$ is already defined by a formula (see code). If you fixed an arbitary value, it won't update the value.

Comment: and I'm still getting the error message with your script when I change the values. Maybe as I am working on my laptop, maybe the computation is too heavy?

Comment: @Jelmes. I repeat: there is no definition of `ω` in the code you posted. It's appearance in an expression is not a definition. If `ω = Sqrt[9.81*H])`, which it suggested by expression you use in your 3D plot, you must either substitute `Sqrt[9.81*H])` for `ω` or make an explicit definition.

Comment: Ah yes, I noticed that. Would I put it at the start of the code before the manipulate, or inside?

Comment: You noticed what? Is my conjecture that `ω = Sqrt[9.81*H])` correct? Your last comment is mystifying.

Comment: I noticed that I hadn't defined $\omega$. Thank you for spotting that.