# Showing a Plot3D and a StreamPlot on one Manipulated Graphic

Tags: manipulate, warning-messages

I'm trying to combine a `Plot3D` and a `StreamPlot` to one Manipulate Graphics diagram so that the `StreamPlot` appears on the $x-y$ axis. Was wondering how this could be done because my attempt does not work. This question is not a duplicate of an earlier post which was about a possible error that kept appearing. This is something completely different!

```
    Waves =
Plot3D[Re[
H + Amp*Exp[-y*Abs[f]/Sqrt[9.81*H]]*
Exp[I*(k*x - (Sqrt[9.81*H])*t)]],
{x, -80000, 80000},
{y, 0, 100000},
PlotPoints -> 30, MeshStyle -> None,
PlotStyle -> Directive[
Opacity[0.65], Blue, Specularity[LightBlue, 10]
]
];
VelocityDiagram =
Dynamic[
StreamPlot[{Sqrt[9.81/H]*
Re[Amp*Exp[-y*Abs[f]/Sqrt[9.81*H]]*
Exp[I*(k*x - (Sqrt[9.81*H])*t)]], 0},
{x, -80000, 80000},
{y, 0, 100000}
]
];
Manipulate[
Show[Waves, VelocityDiagram,
PlotRange -> {0, H + Amp}, 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .6}, FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}],
{{t, 0, "Time {s}"}, 0, 1000},
{{Amp, 20, "Wave Amplitude"}, 0, H},
{{k, 0, "Waves per Metre (x-direction)"}, 0, 0.0005},
{{H, 100, "Depth"}, 0, 500},
{{f, 0, "Coriolis Coefficient"}, -0.001, 0.001}
]`
```

Comment: You can start with: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65401/5478

Comment: Well I can't because that's not what I want. I want a Plot3D with a 2D vector plot (StreamPlot) $\left(u_x,~u_y\right)$ plotted beneath it on the x-y plane ($z=0$).

Comment: Then don't map it on sphere but a plane? You can also try `Texture`.

Comment: I didn't say I wanted to plot it on a sphere though? I said in the question, to plot the streamplot on the x-y plane

Comment: I'll check that out though, thank you

Comment: Yes I know, I didn't say it is a duplicate, I meant the method is applicable here.

Comment: No, I don't see the `Texture` working either. I just want a Plot3D with a StreamPlot projected onto the x-y plane

Comment: What about your velocity diagram being a texture for a polygon on x-y plane?

Comment: That's an interesting solution!

Comment: Is there not a way with `Show`? I know it's possible with Contour plots, so I figured it must be possible with a `StreamPlot`

Comment: First you need to have something to `Show`, it only combines 2d or 3d graphics but not 2d with 3d. So either remap coordinates from 2D to the plan as shown in linked example or use Texture with a polygon. Here is another related case [80743](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80743/5478)

Comment: Ok, that's what I'm now thinking. Thank you! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting errors when evaluating a Manipulate expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148554/getting-errors-when-evaluating-a-manipulate-expression)

Comment: Did you read the question, @m_goldberg? Indeed, it's the same person, but it's a different question. Let me clarify my question: Is it possible to place a `StreamPlot`/`VectorPlot` on the $x-y$ axis of a `Plot3D` and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to plot the `StreamPlot` on a plane with the `z` value at the origin let's first create an example.

```
sp = With[
  {
   t = 0,
   Amp = 20,
   k = 0,
   H = 100,
   f = 0
   },
  StreamPlot[{Sqrt[9.81/H]*
     Re[Amp*Exp[-y*Abs[f]/Sqrt[9.81*H]]*
       Exp[I*(k*x - (Sqrt[9.81*H])*t)]], 0},
    {x, -80000, 80000}, {y, 0, 100000}]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can extract out a portion that contains arrows and it looks like this:

```
sp[[1, 2, 3, 3]]

(* {{Arrowheads[{{0.02, 1.}}], 
  Arrow[{{54421.9, 81872.3}, {56855.8, 81872.3}, {59289.7, 
     81872.3}, {60775.2, 81872.3}, {62260.7, 81872.3}, {63746.2, 
     81872.3}, {65231.7, 81872.3}, {66717.2, 81872.3}, {67686.4, 
     81872.3}}]}, {Arrowheads[{{0.0180664, 1.}}], 
  Arrow[{{68018., 81872.3}, {68202.8, 81872.3}, {69688.3, 
     81872.3}, {71173.8, 81872.3}, {72659.3, 81872.3}, {74144.8, 
     81872.3}, {75630.3, 81872.3}, {77115.9, 81872.3}, {78601.4, 
     81872.3}, {80000., 81872.3}}]}} *)
```

We will want to replace a two dimensional point contained within an `Arrow` with a three dimensional point that has a `z` value of 0. Here is a simple example:

```
Arrow[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}] /. 
 Arrow[point_] :> Arrow[Cases[point, {x_, y_} -> {x, y, 0}]]

(* Arrow[{{1, 2, 0}, {3, 4, 0}}] *)
```

and a slightly more challenging example in a nested list along with `Arrowheads`.

```
{
  {Arrowheads[{0.02, 1}], 
   Arrow[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]}, {Arrowheads[{0.02, 1}], 
   Arrow[{{5, 6}, {7, 8}}]}
  } /. Arrow[point_] :> Arrow[Cases[point, {x_, y_} -> {x, y, 0}]]

(* {{Arrowheads[{0.02, 1}], 
  Arrow[{{1, 2, 0}, {3, 4, 0}}]}, {Arrowheads[{0.02, 1}], 
  Arrow[{{5, 6, 0}, {7, 8, 0}}]}} *)
```

Now let's see if we can use `Show` and make a 3D plot of the 2D `sp` figure.

```
With[
 {
  t = 0,
  Amp = 20,
  k = 0.0001,
  H = 100,
  f = 0
  },
 Graphics3D[
  sp[[1]] /. 
   Arrow[point_] :> Arrow[Cases[point, {x_, y_} -> {x, y, 0}]],
  PlotRange -> {0, H + Amp},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .6},
  Axes -> True
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally we use `Manipulate` in order to see the changes as the parameters change. Note that the `Dynamic` that was wrapping the `StreamPlot` is dropped as everything contained within `Manipulate` is already wrapped in `Dynamic`.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot3D[
   Re[H + 
     Amp*Exp[-y*Abs[f]/Sqrt[9.81*H]]*Exp[I*(k*x - (Sqrt[9.81*H])*t)]],
   {x, -80000, 80000},
   {y, 0, 100000},
   PlotPoints -> 30,
   MeshStyle -> None,
   PlotStyle -> Directive[
     Opacity[0.65],
     Blue,
     Specularity[LightBlue, 10]
     ],
   PlotRange -> {0, H + Amp},
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .6}
   ],
  Graphics3D[
   StreamPlot[{Sqrt[9.81/H]*
        Re[Amp*Exp[-y*Abs[f]/Sqrt[9.81*H]]*
          Exp[I*(k*x - (Sqrt[9.81*H])*t)]], 0}, {x, -80000, 
       80000}, {y, 0, 100000}][[1]] /. 
    Arrow[point_] :> Arrow[Cases[point, {x_, y_} -> {x, y, 0}]]
   ]
  ],
 {{t, 0, "Time {s}"}, 0, 1000},
 {{Amp, 20, "Wave Amplitude"}, 0, H},
 {{k, 0.0001, "Waves per Metre (x-direction)"}, 0, 0.0005},
 {{H, 100, "Depth"}, 0, 500},
 {{f, 0, "Coriolis Coefficient"}, -0.001, 0.001}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is really good! Thank you so much!